# Unknown Provider when i try to check Auth

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularjs-ng-route

Hi im having a problem when in trying to check the Auth status with firebaseAuth on my application

Here is my sample code

```
angular
          .module('starterApp', ['ngMaterial', 'ngAnimate', 'menu', 'about', 'purpose', 'streaming', 'contacta','inicio','login' ,'firebase'])
          .config(function($mdThemingProvider, $mdIconProvider){

              $mdIconProvider
                  .defaultIconSet("./assets/svg/avatars.svg", 128)
                  .icon("menu"       , "./assets/svg/menu.svg"        , 24)
                  .icon("share"      , "./assets/svg/share.svg"       , 24)
                  .icon("google_plus", "./assets/svg/google_plus.svg" , 512)
                  .icon("hangouts"   , "./assets/svg/hangouts.svg"    , 512)
                  .icon("twitter"    , "./assets/svg/twitter.svg"     , 512)
                  .icon("phone"      , "./assets/svg/phone.svg"       , 512);

                  $mdThemingProvider.theme('default')
                      .primaryPalette('teal')
                      .accentPalette('red');

                  $mdThemingProvider.theme('docs-dark', 'default')
                      .primaryPalette('yellow')
                      .dark();

          }).value('FirebaseUrl', 'https://infinityTV.firebaseio.com/')
          .run((["$rootScope", "$location", function($rootScope, $location) {
              $rootScope.$on("$routeChangeError", function(event, next, previous, error) {
                // We can catch the error thrown when the $requireAuth promise is rejected
                // and redirect the user back to the home page
                if (error === "AUTH_REQUIRED") {
                  $location.path("/login");
                }
              });
            }]));
```

and this is the route controller of one of my modules

```
  (function(){
'use strict';

angular.module('inicio')
       .config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider','Auth',   InicioRoutes]);

function InicioRoutes($routeProvider, $locationProvider, $q){
  $routeProvider
  .when('/inicio', {
    templateUrl: 'src/pages/inicio/view/content.html',
    controller: 'InicioController',
    controllerAs: 'page',
    resolve: {
      // controller will not be loaded until $waitForAuth resolves
      // Auth refers to our $firebaseAuth wrapper in the example above
      'currentAuth': ['Auth', function(Auth) {
        // $waitForAuth returns a promise so the resolve waits for it to complete
        return Auth.$waitForAuth();
      }]
    }
  });
 }

 })();
```

Im following the tutorial on firebase documentation but somehow im unable to make tath work since in literaly new to angular.

EDIT

Forgot the stack trace

```
angular.js:68 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate   module starterApp due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module inicio due to:
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: Auth
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.5/$injector/unpr?p0=Auth
   at http://127.0.0.1:8080/bower_components/angular/angular.js:68:12
at http://127.0.0.1:8080/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4458:19
at getService    (http://127.0.0.1:8080/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4611:39)
at injectionArgs    (http://127.0.0.1:8080/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4635:58)
at Object.invoke    (http://127.0.0.1:8080/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4657:18)
at runInvokeQueue (http://127.0.0.1:8080/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4558:35)
at http://127.0.0.1:8080/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4567:11
at forEach   (http://127.0.0.1:8080/bower_components/angular/angular.js:322:20)
at loadModules (http://127.0.0.1:8080/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4548:5)
at http://127.0.0.1:8080/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4565:40
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.5/$injector/modulerr?p0=inicio&p1=Error%3A%…    F%2F127.0.0.1%3A8080%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3A4565%3A40
at http://127.0.0.1:8080/bower_components/angular/angular.js:68:12
at http://127.0.0.1:8080/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4587:15
at forEach (http://127.0.0.1:8080/bower_components/angular/angular.js:322:20)
at loadModules (http://127.0.0.1:8080/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4548:5)
at http://127.0.0.1:8080/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4565:40
at forEach (http://127.0.0.1:8080/bower_components/angular/angular.js:322:20)
at loadModules (http://127.0.0.1:8080/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4548:5)
at createInjector (http://127.0.0.1:8080/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4470:19)
at doBootstrap (http://127.0.0.1:8080/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1746:20)
at bootstrap (http://127.0.0.1:8080/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1767:12)
 http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.5/$injector/modulerr?p0=starterApp&p1=Error…F%2F127.0.0.1%3A8080%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3A1767%3A12)
```

Comment: I think `Auth` is not a provider, which you had injected in `config` function..